# Changing the default font size and font color when adding text in Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

Is there any way to change the default font size and font color when adding text in Adobe Acrobat DC? By default font size and font color, and I mean the font size and font color that are set right after opening Adobe Acrobat DC.

[image]

Comment: You can change the default font and size but I do not see color.  Adobe, Edit Preferences, Content Editing:  Choose your font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may change the default font size but not the font color. From the comment section:

> You can change the default font and size but I do not see color. Adobe, Edit Preferences, Content Editing: Choose your font. [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john) [Dec 11, 2021 at 22:29](https://superuser.com/questions/1692556/changing-the-default-font-size-and-font-color-when-adding-text-in-adobe-acrobat#comment2602770_1692556)